# CodeIgniter - form_checkbox and a required check

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a little checkbox on a signup form im creating which 'must' be checked before the user is allowed to continue ... Im finding it difficult to figure out how to do this with the form_validation functions as well, basically the 'agree to terms and conditions' checkbox MUST be checked in order for the user to continue, if not, an error message displayed, the code i have at the moment is below, if someone could give me a bit of a helping hand that would be great.

Ok, in my view i have the following

```
$agreeCheck = array( 'name' => 'agreeCheck', 'id' => 'agreeCheck', 'value' => 'agree', 'checked' => set_checkbox('agreeCheck', 'agree', FALSE));
<?php echo form_checkbox($agreeCheck); ?>
```

and then in my controller i have the following

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('agreeCheck', 'Agree to the Terms and Conditions', 'required');
```

At the moment, it only remembers the value that was clicked if there is a submission, except if its not checked, it doesnt return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('agreeCheck', 'Agree to the Terms and Conditions', 'required|isset');
```

*Try this out:*

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('agreeCheck', '...', 'callback_terms_check');
```

And then set up this method in the controller:

```
function terms_check() {
    if (isset($_POST['agreeCheck'])) return true;
    $this->form_validation->set_message('terms_check', 'THIS IS SOOOOO REQUIRED, DUDE!');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Weird that doesn't work. Check OP for annoying callback workaround.

Comment: Hmmm the callback workaround didnt work either ... im thinking something is going wrong in the array for setting up the form_checkbox

Comment: They are both the same - <input type="checkbox" name="agreeCheck" value="agree" id="agreeCheck"  />

Comment: `set_checkbox()` will actually return `" checked='checked'"` if the checkbox is checked. Why not modify that bit to `'checked' => (bool)set_checkbox(...`? From searching around a bit, it seems like CodeIgniter's checkbox handling is spotty at best.

Comment: I figured the problem .... I forgot to echo out the form validation errors *sigh* ... Its been a long night ... Thanks for your help :)